# Slow page load in wordpress sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

So basically, I have no clue about PHP, but somehow, I managed to get this script working. 

(The script checks if a livestream is online [on www.own3d.tv], if it's online, it displays the name of the streamer and the viewers. If it's offline, it displays nothing.)


I inserted it into my Wordpress siderbar. But the thing is, when I open my page, all the other content loads up, but the sidebar takes a few seconds to load. I guess it takes so long to check the livestreams. 
So, is there a way to let it load faster, or to let it load the other stuff on the sidebar first?

Thanks in advance for your replies.
Regards

```
<html>
<body>
<p style="width:300px; height:250px; padding:1px; border:5px solid #66a">
<?php





function  pageTime()
{
static $_pt;
    if($_pt == 0) $_pt = microtime(true);
    else return (string)(round(microtime(true)-$_pt ,3));
}

pageTime();





//Froggen
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=112348");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Froggen - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/112348/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}



//Athene
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=42146");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Athene - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/42146/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}




//Guardsman Bob
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=34046");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Guardsman Bob - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/34046/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}



//The Rain Man
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=38853");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'The Rain Man - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/38853/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//TheOddOne
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=6416");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'TheOddOne - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/6416/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//Dyrus
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=37905");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Dyrus - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/37905/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//Xpecial
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=10953");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Xpecial - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/10953/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//Chaox
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=33356");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Chaox - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/33356/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//Wickd
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=18755");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Wickd - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/18755/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}


//Lapaka
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=214");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Lapaka - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/214/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}



//Snoopeh
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=112350");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Snoopeh - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/112350/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}

//Dedrayon
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=265558");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Dedrayon - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/265558/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}



//Malaco
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=259259");
$resultlive = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/isLive");
$resultviewers = $xml->xpath("/own3dReply/liveEvent/liveViewers");

if ($resultlive[0] == 'true'){
echo 'Malaco - Viewers: '; echo ($resultviewers[0]); echo ' - <a href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/259259/">Watch now!</a> <br>';
}
else {
echo '';
}




?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the LiveCheck API is pretty slow. You might want to use AJAX to load the viewer count number. That way you can fill in the static info right away. If you have jQuery installed in the head of your files, a simple script tag with the following will do it. I'll add a snippet in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the code, but it's stuck at "Loading...". It won't show the viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a simple text widget in your sidebar and pasting this into the content. Just make sure your theme has jQuery installed:

```
Froggen - Viewers: <a class="live-viewers" href="http://www.own3d.tv/live/112348/">Loading...</a> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=112348", function (res) {
    var xml = $.parseXML(res);
    $('.live-viewers').text(res.own3dReply.liveEvent.liveViewers[0];
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the code, but it's stuck at "Loading...". It won't show the viewers

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the results of those simplexml_load_file() calls. The first call would take the normal amount of time, but subsequent calls would load the cached data and perform very quickly.

Comment: I'm very sorry for asking this, but how do I do that? As I said, I don't know anything about php. Sorry, please help me out